# Ionic2 + Application

Tags: angular, ionic3, ionic2-select

I'm a bit confused about the application instantiation hierarchy, especially for providers. So basically you do the following in **app.module.ts**

```
import { myService} from '../providers/myService/myService';
```

and add it to the

```
@NgModule collection
    providers:[
        bla bla,
        myService
    ]
```

Now if I import and instantiate `MyService` in the **app.components.ts** does that make it a singleton for the whole app?

Every time I have wanted to use it on a page I have done the import and page constructor thing (e.g. `myServ: myService`)...but does that create a new instance or use the one created from **app.components.ts**.

I would love an explanation of the life-cycle of the components so the I know what I'm doing (well, as best as possible!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injected Services in Ionic2+ are indeed Singletons and Ionic will instantiate and configure them during framework initialization.